# std::chrono / date:: year_month_date and calendar AND time arithmetic

Tags: c++, date, c++20, c++-chrono

I have a calendar date and a "time" as in "2023-06-30 22:35:10"
I'd like to add a "calendar" day. So what I'd like to get is "2023-07-01 22:35:10".

Now I could

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = sys_days{ June / 25 / 2023 } + 22h + 35min + 10s;
tp = tp + 24h;
```

but up to my understanding, a calendar day is not always 24h. The problem gets even more complicated if I've to take into account time zones.

So I could (seems to work)

```
year_month_day ymd { June / 30 / 2023 };
ymd = ymd.year()/ymd.month()/(ymd.day() + days{1}); // ymd.ok() == false
ymd = sys_days{ymd}; // not really needed if next step...
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = sys_days{ymd} + 22h + 35min + 10s;
```

and for localized date + time (??)

```
auto locTime = date::locate_zone("Europe/Rome");
year_month_day ymd { June / 30 / 2023 };
ymd = ymd.year()/ymd.month()/(ymd.day() + days{1}); // ymd.ok() == false
std::chrono::sys_seconds tp { date::sys_days(ymd) + 22h + 35min + 10s };
date::zoned_time<std::chrono::seconds> tz = date::zoned_time<std::chrono::seconds>(locTime, tp);
```

Is this the correct way to go? Any simpler way?
Any way to at least avoid creating tp to get tz?

Comment: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/issues/178

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on if the date time 2023-06-30 22:35:10 is UTC, or with respect to some time zone such as "Europe/Rome".

If it is UTC, then yes, 1 day is always exactly 86400s (`chrono::system_clock` does not count leap seconds).  So your first code looks good to me.  I might have written it with `days` instead of `hours`:

```
auto tp = sys_days{June / 25 / 2023} + 22h + 35min + 10s;
tp += days{1};
```

However if this a date time local to Rome, and you want to ensure the same time of day after the addition of the day, then it is best to do the arithmetic in local time.

**Aside:** All `time_point`s and clocks that start with `sys` (`system_clock`, `sys_days`, `sys_seconds`, `sys_time<milliseconds>`, etc.) model [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  This is UTC neglecting leap seconds.  If the `time_point` is prefixed with `local`, that refers to a local `time_point` which can be associated with a `time_zone`.  One associates it by using it with a specific `time_zone`. **/Aside:**

To change this to a local time use `local_days` in place of `sys_days` above:

```
auto tp = local_days{June / 25 / 2023} + 22h + 35min + 10s;
tp += days{1};
```

The answer is the same.  Under the hood, the math is the same.  However if you want the UTC equivalent, that may or may not be exactly 86400s later.

One can get that UTC equivalent with:

```
auto tp_utc = locate_zone("Europe/Rome")->to_sys(tp);
```

The type of `tp_utc` is now a `sys_time` with whatever precision `tp` has.

Your last code example looks correct, but may not be doing what you think. In that example `tp` is a UTC time stamp.  And when you pair it with "Europe/Rome" within the `zoned_time`, that allows you to compute the local time in Rome that is equivalent to the UTC time stamp `tp`.

So in summary, use `local_time` to compute local time, and `sys_time` to compute in UTC.  And use `time_zone` and/or `zoned_time` to translate back and forth between `local_time` and `sys_time`.

`zoned_time` is just a convenience wrapper around the data structure `{time_zone const*, sys_time}`.